# Proportion numbers calculation. 5000 proportion of 240

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find the proportion of numbers. I built a circular range slider using Jcanvas.
The angle total is 240 degree. I would like to keep a number between this value.

Example: 5,000 proportion of 240. Basically, when I slide the handle toward the 240 mark it will equal 5,000.

5000 will be the 240 mark, anywhere in between the number will adjust saying 120 mark will equal 2500.

I hope I'm explaining this clearly. Trying to expand my Jquery math knowledge.

Thanks...

Comment: fiddle please. So that we can check code

Comment: So if 5000 = 240, then 5000 / 240 = about 21 (20.833333). So each mark on your slider is worth 21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each increment in your `slider` should add `5000/240` to the actual value.

Thus:

```
0 in slider = 0
120 in slider = 120 * 5000 / 240 = 2500
240 in slider = 5000
```

In pseudocode:

```
value := sliderValue * 5000 / 240
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct. 5000 will be the 240 mark, anywhere in between the number will adjust saying 120 mark will equal 2500.

Comment: Hey, I got it now. I will post to fiddle once I get a good example going. This did it for me sliderValue * 5000 / 240 :)

Comment: Hope I did it correctly. I'm new to stackoverflow but been on this website for years just looking around solving problems. Thanks again.

Comment: @ifelse great, way to go :)